# how to change the QR code color in Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, qr-code

Hi I'm using MatLab to generate my QR code, basically [this toolbox](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49808-qr-code-generator-1-1-based-on-zxing?focused=7172243&tab=example) basing on zxing library.

I need to change the color of the code into blue. I mean the black pattern part needs to be blue. I guess its just the setting, right? But I didn't find the right one to change. Do somebody know how to do it?

Thank you!

Example codes:

```
m='qq';
qr=qrcode_gen(m);
colormap(gray);
imagesc(qr);
axis image;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line setting the colormap you prefer:

```
colormap(gray);
```

For example:

```
colormap(parula(5))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to change the colormap from `gray` to `blue` before, but it doesn't work. Now I know its because I can't just write `blue` there. Could you tell me where I can find all the setting colors? Also what about the background color? Thanks!!

Comment: Colors in matlab are vectors of 3 doubles (R, G and B).

Comment: Yeah, I know about this. But how do I know the name of the colors I need. For example, here I want blue in the colormap, but I cant just write blue here. Instead, I need to write parula. So where is this parula from? Where can I find all the names of the colors I can use?

Comment: Parula is a colormap (a vector of colors). If you want a single color, blue for example: [0 0 1];

Comment: ok, I got it. I just search colormap in Matlab and I find the examples. Thank you!